# PySpark: How to get the average time it took for one column to change value?

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I have a table which specifies whether a chatroom is connected or not:

```
+--------+-----------+-------------+------+
| roomId | timeStamp | isConnected | col3 |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------+
|      1 |     10000 | true        |  ... |
|      2 |      9000 | true        |  ... |
|      1 |      8000 | true        |  ... |
|      3 |      7000 | true        |  ... |
|      2 |      6000 | false       |  ... |
|      3 |      5000 | false       |  ... |
|      1 |      4000 | false       |  ... |
|      1 |      3000 | false       |  ... |
|      3 |      2000 | true        |  ... |
|      3 |      1000 | false       |  ... |
+--------+-----------+-------------+------+
```

For each `roomId`, I want to know the average time it took for the `isConnected` value to turn from each first occurrence of `false` to `true`. In other words, I want to know the average time it took to for each chatrooms to reconnect whenever their connection is down.

```
+--------+------------+
| roomId | avgConTime |
+--------+------------+
|      1 |       5000 |
|      2 |       3000 |
|      3 |       1500 |
+--------+------------+
```

For example, `roomId = 1` is not connected at `timestamp = 3000`. It managed to connect again at `timestamp = 8000`. So the average time it took to reconnect is `5000`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a bit long, but there are actually a lot of intermediary steps to achieve this simple result :

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

w = Window.partitionBy("roomId").orderBy("timeStamp")

df = df.withColumn(
    "_id",
    F.sum(
        F.when(F.col("isConnected") == F.lag("isConnected").over(w), 0).otherwise(1)
    ).over(w),
)

df_agg = df.groupBy("roomId", "_id").agg(
    F.min("timeStamp").alias("timeStamp"), F.first("isConnected").alias("isConnected")
)

df_agg = (
    df_agg.withColumnRenamed("timeStamp", "timeStamp_start")
    .withColumn(
        "timeStamp_end",
        F.lead("timeStamp_start").over(Window.partitionBy("roomId").orderBy("_id")),
    )
    .where("timeStamp_end is not null")
    .where("not isConnected")
    .withColumn("duration", F.col("timeStamp_end") - F.col("timeStamp_start"))
)

df_agg.groupBy("roomId").agg(F.avg("duration")).show()

+------+-------------+                                                          
|roomId|avg(duration)|
+------+-------------+
|     1|       5000.0|
|     3|       1500.0|
|     2|       3000.0|
+------+-------------+
```